# MUTE A MICROPHONE IN C#

Tags: c#-4.0, microphone, mute

i am developing a sip client using c#.net and in which it has microphone control through which i can mute and unmute the microphone and it works well when i mute and unmute from my application and the issue is when i open my application and mute the mic and same time if i open skype there is issue with mic what i undersatnd is when i mute a mic in my application it is muting all over..can any one guide me how to mute the mic only in my application which does not affects other applications like skype.. etc..here is the code for mute and unmute microphone..

```
private void MicMuteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MixerLine micline;
        mMixers = new Mixers();
        mMixers.Playback.MixerLineChanged += new       WaveLib.AudioMixer.Mixer.MixerLineChangeHandler(mMixer_MixerLineChanged);
        mMixers.Recording.MixerLineChanged += new WaveLib.AudioMixer.Mixer.MixerLineChangeHandler(mMixer_MixerLineChanged);
        micline = mMixers.Recording.UserLines.GetMixerFirstLineByComponentType(MIXERLINE_COMPONENTTYPE.SRC_MICROPHONE);
        if ((string)MicMuteButton.Image.Tag == "Disabled")
        {
            micline.Mute = false;
            MicMuteButton.Image = Properties.Resources.MicrophoneEnabled;
            MicMuteButton.Image.Tag = "Enabled";
            ttu.SetToolTip(MicMuteButton, "Mute");
        }
        else if ((string)MicMuteButton.Image.Tag == "Enabled")
        {
            micline.Mute = true;
            MicMuteButton.Image = Properties.Resources.MicrophoneDisabled;
            MicMuteButton.Image.Tag = "Disabled";
            ttu.SetToolTip(MicMuteButton, "Unmute");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are using NAudio for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft wrote a separate framework for lower level graphic and audio called DirectX. Maybe you should try.